# Should we give a Site-map page in Mobile Websites?

Tags: website-design, mobile-web, sitemap

I noticed Mobile website's are not having site-map page? Is there any reason behind it?

Should we give a Site-map page in Mobile Websites?

Can it be useful?

I think user can see the sitemap page and choose the page where he want to go in less clicks and less time.

An example of Sitemap in Footer of a Desktop Website

[image]

We can make it mobile compatible

Comment: A sitemap creates a bigger page with no real content. A simple link to the sitemap should be enough.

Comment: @Barfieldmv - yes as in my question title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to limited space, mobile sites should include only essentials. In my opinion, a site map is not essential. Most sites implement it for SEO purposes. The pages are rarely designed for "live" users.

**I would not have a sitemap on a mobile site.**

Comment: I've rarely seen the use in a sitemap from a desktop paradigm for that matter. It just seems like an awkward way to admit "I couldn't lay out effective navigation"

Answer (score 1):

I am with SirTapTap that sitemaps for live users are usually an indication that the navigation is not up to scratch. So I do not see the point in having them at all, and I only use them when I am trying to find something on a site an I cannot.

So the fact that I would not particualrly support full site maps on desktop pages means I would not support them on mobile pages either. Make sure that the searching and navigation are suitable and so they are not needed.

I am more in support of the footer sitemaps - they do serve the navigational purpose of the footer, and are better than page sitemaps. But not for mobile sites.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on your take of what a mobile website should be (either a mobile optimised version of your complete website OR a subset of your website content).  If it's the later, i think that the very bottom of your page can act as the site map (and navigation) of your website.